# Blender Fluid Flow object and fluid do not align

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to do a render with an inflow on top of some simple terrain however whenever I try and bake the data the fluid does not align with the inflow object. The first image below has the inflow object highlighted and the fluid is off by some seemingly random offset. The offset fluid does in fact interact with the terrain effector however in its offset position.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Domain dimensions

[image]

Domain Location

[image]

As for things I've tried, I've tried reloading the blender file multiple times, changing the resolution of the domain (This only made the offset inflow create more fluid particles it did not change the offset of the fluid in any way), changed the size of the inflow object, and tried removing the terrain effector from the domain this also did not change anything about the location of the fluid.

I genuinely have no idea what else I could change about the domain to make it behave appropriately as every video I see about inflows not working properly has to do with the fluid just not showing up rather than not having the fluid not align properly. Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out. Apparently, the X and Z dimensions are too far apart. As soon as I made the X size bigger than the Z size it began to behave properly. This is a weird interaction I did not know about.